# Good/Simple shopping cart example using asp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart, sample

Is there a Good/Simple shopping cart example using asp.net mvc and jquery? Any suggestion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rob Conery wrote a series of blog posts about the StoreFront application.

**EDIT** Blog posts [have moved](http://wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront), and the beginning post can be found [in the archives](http://wekeroad.com/2008/04/07/mvc-storefront-part-1).

Comment: As an update, the blog is now a series of videos (25 of them) located on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-1-architectural-discussion-and-overview).